# How to get content of a specific page?

Tags: wordpress

I want example to get the content of the page with the slug `sasd` that is private I only want it to appear in sidebar..

I have tried this(page):

```
<?php
$the_slug = 'sasd';
$args=array(
  'name' => $the_slug,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'private',
  'numberposts' => 1
);
$my_posts = get_posts($args);
if( $my_posts ) {
echo 'ID on the first post found '.$my_posts[0]->ID;
}
?>
```

Comment: what's the problem with the current code? should be displaying `ID`, is it not?

Comment: Also I want it to display the content and not the ID (does not appear)

Comment: I got the ID :) It was a page instead of post...

Comment: Just how do I get the content instead of the id?`

Comment: you can use `get_page` directly if you're looking for contents of a page. You wrote `age` instead of `page` in your code above btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code is not working... but it should...

here's my test result..

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 31
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2013-01-13 04:23:39
            [post_date_gmt] => 2013-01-13 04:23:39
            [post_content] => fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd
            [post_title] => sasd
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => private
            [comment_status] => open
            [ping_status] => open
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => sasd
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2013-01-13 04:23:39
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2013-01-13 04:23:39
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://localhost/wordpress/?p=31
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => post
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

)
ID on the first post found 31
```

Please make sure you have `sasd` as the title of the post. which has a permalink like this `http://localhost/wordpress/2013/01/13/sasd/`

to get it to display the content, you need to do it like this: `$my_posts[0]->post_content`

or just take a look at the `WP_Post Object` I've posted and see the pattern on how to get other data..

Answer (score 0):

When you got your post:

```
foreach( $my_posts as $post ) :
     setup_postdata($post); 
     the_content(); // displays the content of the post
endforeach;
```

Reference for `the_content`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Comment: the_content() echoes automatically.

Comment: I don't even know how I could write something like that! Correcting it.